# .NET Core: How To Add Configuration Options To ServiceCollection When TOptions Type Is Dependent On String Value?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, configuration, appsettings

I am binding to an appsettings config section in my host build using the following:-

```
services.Configure<MySettings1>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("TheSection"));
```

I only want to bind one section, but the actual type I want to bind to is dependent on a string variable myTypeName and it could be one of 3 types - MySettings1, MySettings2 or MySettings3.

So what i want to do is (which i know is not possible):-

```
var myTypeName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_TYPE_NAME");
services.Configure<myTypeName>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("TheSection"));
```

The section can have different structures for each of the three types and it can be called TheSection or something different for each type (that bit is ok as it is already a string).

I couldn't see any overloads for the Configure method in the ms docs that don't require a type, but i am no expert in generics so was hoping someone could point me in the right direction (or alternatively, tell me i shouldn't do this coz of xyz :).

Comment: Can you show more code to better represent what it is you are actually trying to do. I got confused about the myTypeName variable and where it comes from as it relates to setting the configuration. Include what the section might look like

Comment: Are you saying that the config section "TheSection" can have different 'shapes' and that you want to bind that section to different types?

Comment: hi @Nkosi, i added how i populate myTypeName, does that help? The settings sections themselves have different structures with each one mapping to MySettings1, 2 and 3 respectively

Comment: hi @DavidOsborne yes that's it, MySettings1/2/3 have different shapes, i've updated the question to make that clearer, thanks :)

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I would suggest reviewing the current design of the system in question.

Comment: @Nkosi i have added my design description below, please let me know if you think the design is bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the use of a string here, reflection would need to be used to get the desired behavior at run-time.

```
//...

string myTypeName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_TYPE_NAME");
//Gets the Type with the specified name
Type myType = Type.GetType(myTypeName, throwOnError: false, ignoreCase: true);
if (myType == null) {
    //...fail early? throw meaningful exception?
} else {
    IConfiguration section = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("TheSection");
    if (section == null) {
        //...fail early? throw exception.
    }

    //using reflection to invoke the Configure<TOption> extension
    Type extensionClass = typeof(OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions);
    //get the desired extension method by name and using the expected arguments
    Type[] parameterTypes = new[] { typeof(IServiceCollection), typeof(IConfiguration) };
    string extensionName = nameof(OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure);
    MethodInfo configureExtension = extensionClass.GetMethod(extensionName, parameterTypes);
    //make the closed generic extension using the run time type from environment
    MethodInfo extensionMethod = configureExtension.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
    //invoke the extension "services.Configure<myType>(section);"
    extensionMethod.Invoke(services, section);
}

//...
```

The main parts of the above could be extracted and made into an extension.

Having to resort to this level configuration could be an indication of design issues with the system in question that can potentially lead maintainability problems going forward.

This also assumes that the actual type is actually being used used in dependent classes.

```
//ctor
public MyClass(IOptions<myType> options);
```

Comment: hi @nkosi, many thanks, i will mark this as the answer as i have not used reflection much before and so i think this is the best answer especially as it gives me more insight into how i could use reflection in the future! i will also def keep in mind to be wary of when to use it to avoid any potential design issues :)

Answer (score 1):

This is far from perfect, but it should get you going and give you something you could refine.

You could define types for the different settings 'shapes' something like this:

```csharp
abstract class SettingsBase { }

class DerivedSettingsOne : SettingsBase { }

class DerivedSettingsTwo : SettingsBase { }
```

Then create a factory that knows how to translate the string into a type. However, it can only return the abstract base as it has to support all derived types:

```csharp
static class SettingsFactory {
   SettingsBase GetSettings(string typeName, IConfigurationSection configSection) {
      return 
         typeName switch {
            "DerivedSettingsOne" => new DerivedSettingsOne { // props here },
            "DerivedSettingsTwo" => new DerivedSettingsTwo { // props here },
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(direction)
         };
   }
}
```

Then you can register the factory, capturing the value from the environment variable and the config section, that will resolve requests for `SettingsBase`.

```csharp
services.AddSingleton(s => {
   return SettingsFactory.GetSettings(
      Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_TYPE_NAME"),
      hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("TheSection")
});
```

You can now declare types that need the settings with a dependency on `SettingsBase` that the IoC container will resolve. The only issue is that consumers of `SettingsBase` will need to cast it to the derived type they need to work with:

```csharp
class MyClass {
   MyClass(SettingsBase settings) {
      var expectedSettings = settings as DerivedSettingsTwo;
   }
}
```

Comment: IMO this is a poor design. While you rightly stated it is far from perfect, it is encouraging tight coupling to implementation details.

Comment: Sure. How might it be improved?

Comment: Well, the core problem still has not been clarified by the OP. Which is what lead you down this ill advised path.

Comment: The OP is asking how to do X when the actual problem might actually be Y. We have 3 separate setting types that need to be dynamically configured for injection at run time. Which raises design flags for me in my experience.

Comment: i don't think it is a design issue, i have a fairly simple design, but here it is - i have a host that has a number of worker classes and i want to run only one worker in each of my deployments coz each worker may have different runtime characteristics. so i can either have a host solution per worker and have 20+ solutions with the bulk of the host related code duplicated or i can have a single solution containing the host and load the worker i need dynamically based on the one i want to be run. or i could have a big switch statement to load exactly the right worker using the real type.

Comment: hi @DavidOsborne, many thanks for your reply! i understand that you and nkosi felt it might not be ideal due to the tight coupling, but it was useful for me to see the technique anyways :)

Comment: No problem. We're all learning!